# Do SQL Server stored procedures perform better in network clusters?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-performance

From what I've read, there appears to be marginal performance benefits using stored procedures vs simply building the commands in C# and calling them explicitly in the program's code, at least when it comes to machines that share the server program and db engine (and when the procedures are simple). Most people seem to think it's a 'preference issue', and add a few other minor benefits to justify their case.

However, one I couldn't find any information on, is the benefit of a stored procedure when the database engine is located on a separate physical machine from the main application.

If I am not mistaken, in a server farm, wouldn't a stored procedure offload the processing on some cpu threads from the main server application, and have the primary processing done on the db engine server's cpu instead? Or, is this already done on the db engine's cpu anyways, when the C# libraries 'build' the information for the db engine to process?

Specifically, I have a long-running transaction that I could do multiple calls in a C# transaction block, but I suspect that a stored proc will in fact have a huge performance benefit by reducing the network calls to the db engine, as well as guaranteeing the processing is not being done on the main server application.

Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance gains from a stored procedure (versus something like Dapper or an OR/M like Entity Framework) can vary anywhere from nearly identical to a very noticeable performance improvement.  I don't think your question can be answered without seeing the code that would be translated to a stored procedure.

Having said that, in my experience making a single stored procedure call versus multiple statements from the application code, yes, it would likely be faster.

Comment: In this case, the 'long running transaction' will likely involve a half dozen tables and require conditional processing. To me, it seems like this would have a significant performance gain (less network calls, and guaranteed processing done on a different physical machine), if the db engine is located on a different machine.

Comment: Then there's the maintenance part.  Where is the TSQL in C# stored, is it in compiled code?  updating a stored proc in SQL Server will be much simpler than having to build/compile/release code.

Answer (score 1):

If the SP is just a simple query (ie one SELECT statement) the performance gain is that a SP is pre-compiled.  While the query is running you should not see any difference if it is a query or a SP.

I'm not sure of the effect if the SP is more complicated because this would depend on the query.

Answer (score 1):

The more important benefit of a SP is that all the data are kept in the DBMS instead of being sent back and forward to the client. If you are dealing with large amount of data the benefit is more evident. The difference rises if your DB is located on a different machine and even more if the connection between them is slow.
On the contrary you must consider that a SP usually is not compiled to machine code so if the SP implements very complex logic it could be faster to implement the logic on the client. 
Then you should also consider that moving the business logic to the server is not so good for code maintenance, you could add a technology debit implementing in the DB something that should be in your client code.
So, there isn't a solution valid for all the seasons but usually a well written SP is faster than the same code running on the client

Comment: I agree that, if possible, it would be best to calculate on the client. However, in this scenario, which I may not have been completely clear (my bad), I am presuming the client does not have any cached data to work with and thus would need to load it into tables to do the work. While it might make the calculation quicker, in fairness, pre-loading the tables is part of the cost of processing. Kinda like saying if I line my ducks up in a row, its easier to shoot them, but lining them up takes time too.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues at play here.  As others have said, it kind of depends.  A raw select statement will be barely noticeable.  If there's a hugely complex query then a SP can save a lot of repetitive parsing.  If there's a lot of intermediate data then SP will keep the data local, reducing network traffic.  If your DB has a higher spec than the client it might run faster due to CPU horsepower.

Downsides can be things like bogging down the DB for everyone with processing that could be done on the client.  This is generally if you're running an underpowered SQL server.  Another subtle side to this is that licensing costs for a multi-core DB server can be impressive.  Your $ per cycle on a SQL Server box can be many times what it is on your client.

Comment: Just noticed I've piggybacked off a bit of a necro.  Oops.  Hopefully something useful here.